# Pass nested JSON object in JSON object as string using Angular

Tags: json, angular

This is my JSON object where property `RuleJson` is a nested JSON object. I am having difficulty passing this nested object as a string as the nested json contains `quotation marks` in the `Expression` property. I want to pass `RuleJson` as a string property not as a JSON object from frontend using in Angular. The nested object would be `Deserialize` into a DTO model in backend in C# class object.

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "workflowName": "Test005",
    "ruleJson": {
        "Rules": [
            {
                "RuleName": "VaidateAutoPick",
                "Expression": "!RuleEngineValidationModel.AutoPickFlag == \"abc\""
            }
        ]
    },
    "isActive": true,
    "createdBy": 14,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "createdOn": "2021-08-11T08:12:33.274Z",
    "updatedOn": "2021-08-11T08:12:33.274Z",
    "ruleTypeId": 108
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correct, simple destruction and `JSON.stringify` should solve it:

```js
const data = {
    "id": 0,
    "workflowName": "Test005",
    "ruleJson": {
        "Rules": [
            {
                "RuleName": "VaidateAutoPick",
                "Expression": "!RuleEngineValidationModel.AutoPickFlag == \"abc\""
            }
        ]
    },
    "isActive": true,
    "createdBy": 14,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "createdOn": "2021-08-11T08:12:33.274Z",
    "updatedOn": "2021-08-11T08:12:33.274Z",
    "ruleTypeId": 108
}

const dataWithStrigifiedRuleJson = {
   ...data,
   ruleJson: JSON.stringify(data.ruleJson),
}
```